# Sorting list of objects

Tags: java

I have a list of objects:

```
List<WorkflowError> workflowErrors = new List<WorkflowError>();
```

Of which I am wanting to sort alphabetically on the string field errorCode.

I know I have to use

```
Collections.sort(list,comparator)
```

and write a custom Comparator:

```
public class SortByErrorComparator implements Comparator<WorkflowError>
{
    // Comparator logic    
    return 0;
}
```

I have seen examples of how to do this for a one dimensional list but I can't work out how to begin for a list of objects.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `// comparator logic`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to implement the `compare` method.

```
public class SortByErrorComparator implements Comparator<WorkflowError> {
    public int compare(WorkflowError obj1, WorkflowError obj2) {
        return obj1.getErrorCode().compareTo(obj2.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

And then, you can simply do:

```
Collections.sort(list, new SortByErrorComparator()) ;
```

In the Java world, generally we do it inline using anonymous inner classes as so:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<WorkflowError>() {
    public int compare(WorkflowError obj1, WorkflowError obj2) {
        return obj1.getErrorCode().compareTo(obj2.getErrorCode());
    }
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I didn't know how the compareTo() would behave for strings actually. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your comparator, you have to explain how the specific object should be sorted.

```
if (obj.att1 < obj2.att2)
   ...
```

do you get it?

Answer (score 0):

When sorting the list the sort implementation will use your comparator to compare individual paisr of objects. So what your comparator needs to do is decide, for a given pair of WorkFlowErrors, which comes 'first'.

from what you've said this sounds like just getting the error code from each one and doing a string compairson.

Answer (score 0):

If you will always want to compare WorkflowError objects in this manner, the easiest way is to implement `Comparable<WorkflowError>` on `WorkflowError` itself.

```
public int compareTo(WorkflowError that) {
    return this.getErrorCode().compareTo(that.getErrorCode());
}
```

That's assuming errorCode implements Comparable.